# Flutter: How to overflow a button inside of a box?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to reproduce this layout button
[image]

I created a Stack with a Container and a Positioned button, but I can't set the button out of the box.

```
                  Stack(children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                        border: new Border.all(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        width: 1 
                        )
                      ),
                      child: Text("League of legends")
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      right: 0,
                      bottom: 0,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 9,
                        height: 9,
                        child: new Container(
                          width: 9,
                          height: 9,
                          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    )
                  ])
```

I tried add Padding but without success.

The result of my code is this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of `Stack` has the `overflow` argument, which enables you to choose whether to paint its children outside of its boundary.

By passing in `Overflow.visible` to `overflow` and setting negative values in `right` and `bottom` in `Positioned()`, you can make the circle stick out of the box.

```dart
Stack(
  overflow: Overflow.visible,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      decoration: ...,
      child: ...,
    ),
    Positioned(
      right: -4,
      bottom: -4,
      child: Container(
        width: 9,
        height: 9,
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

I've reduced redundantly nested Containers into one.